# How to display First three letters of the month in android datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

In date Picker I tried to get month in letter others are in integer 
It's returning full name of the month. But i want first threes letters of the month.

i tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MMMM, dd ");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new SimpleDateFormat(new Date()).toString()));
```

output: 2013-October-18

I want output as : 2013-Oct-18

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `MMM`, like this `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd ")`

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.Hopefully this will work...

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
```